# Writing NSAttributedString with images to .doc or .docx filetypes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have NSAttributedStrings with images and I'm able to write it to RTF (no images) and RTFD (with images); however, when I write the NSAttributedString data to .doc and .docx file types, the images don't show up. The code I use to get the data that is written to file is (below is for .doc):

```
[text docFormatFromRange:readRange
      documentAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentOption: NSWordMLTextDocumentType}];
```

The output is as I'd otherwise expect, except that instead of the images I see small icons that say "OBJ" in blue with a dotted-blue line box surrounding the word. Any ideas?